# Как с помощью цикла вывести список на php (WP + ACF)

Tags: wordpress, acf

Вводные: WP + ACF. У меня есть такой список в php.

```
<ul>
 <li><?php the_field('item1') ?></li>
 <li><?php the_field('item2') ?></li>
 <li><?php the_field('item3') ?></li>
 <li><?php the_field('item4') ?></li>
 ...
 <li><?php the_field('item15') ?></li>
</ul>
```

Как можно этот список вывести через цикл? (меняется только цифра)

Comment: Можете использовать цикл [for](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.for.php) например:`<?php for($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++) : ?><li><?php the_field('item' . $i) ?></li><?php endfor; ?>`

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [здесь](https://acfwp.ru/get_fields/) есть пример вывода всех полей в цикле:

```
<?php 

$fields = get_fields();

if( $fields ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $fields as $name => $value ): ?>
            <li><b><?php echo $name; ?></b> <?php echo $value; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Ну и вообще там хорошая [документация](https://acfwp.ru/category/documentation/) на русском по ACF.

Comment: Спасибо попробую. Спасибо за ссылку.